# Autohotkey, numpad buttons not working when used in shortcut

Tags: autohotkey

I have made a simple AHK script to launch applications, however, the numpadkeys used first in the active shortcut does not work alone.

```
Numpad4 & Numpad9::
Run Notepad++
Return

Numpad2 & Numpad3::
    Run CMD
    Return

PrintScreen::
    Run Chrome
    Return
```

For example, Numpad4 and Numpad2 does not work when presses alone, when pressed together with its corresponding shortcut as mentioned in the script the application launches.

-edit
This means that i can type the numbers 1,3,5,6,7,8,9 with the numpad in a text editor or similar, but not 2 or 4. (just to clear that up)
-edit.end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used to implement this hotkey, which as a side-effect prevents the Send command from triggering it.
https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

```
$Numpad4:: Send {Numpad4}

$Numpad9:: Send {Numpad9}

Numpad4 & Numpad9:: Run Notepad
```